# ngShow and ngHide when in a ngRepeat loop, button to add element only first time it shows all the elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angularjs

I have this issue:

Inside a ngRepeat loop the form elements are hidden and only displayed when an edit button is clicked for each element.

There is also a button at the end that adds an element to the list, and it should show the form for only the new empty elemnt added.

When the add button is clicked first time, all the forms are displayed - it is clearly not intended -. But if I show the form elements and afterwards I hide them (submitting the form), when I click to the add button, it does not display all the forms, only the new one - what I actually intended -.

The code is straightforward:

```
<div ng-controller='TriggerCtrl' ng-model='triggers'>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='trigger in triggers'>
            <span ng-hide='edit'>{{trigger.operator}}</span>
            <button ng-click='edit=!edit' ng-hide='edit'>Edit</button>
            <form name='editTrigger' ng-show='edit' ng-submit='submit'>
                <select ng-model='trigger.operator' ng-options='op.value as op.name for op in operators' />
                <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Submit' ng-click='edit=!edit' />
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click='add()'>Add</button>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
function TriggerCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.triggers = [
    {operator: 'gt'}, 
    {operator: 'gte'}
  ];

  $scope.operators = [
    {name: 'greater than', value: 'gt'}, 
    {name: 'greater than equal', value: 'gte'}
  ];

  $scope.add = function () {
    $scope.triggers.push({});
    $scope.edit = true;
  };
};
```

You can see the effect in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gserra/NG76R/1/

To test it, first click to add button and see that all forms are displayed. Then reload, and then first, click on edit and then click on submit. Afterwards, if you click in add button, only the new form will be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with scope inheritance. basically you have a `$scope.edit` in your main controller and each iteration of your ng-repeat has it's own `$scope.edit`. If you change the `$scope.edit` in the parent scope/controller it will change the children `$scope.edit`'s, but changing the children `$scope.edit`'s (e.g. when you click the submit buttons) will not change the global `$scope.edit`. See my fiddle where I try to demonstrate this:

http://jsfiddle.net/773Pf/

There's probably different ways to achieve what you want so I'll just tell you what's wrong right now. One Hint: look into inheritance in javascript specifically objects vs. primitives.

Comment: See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/X9KYU/4/ where I illustrate an example of how inheritance can cuase problems.

Comment: It's something that I thought, but what I do not understand is why clicking in edit, and then in submit in one of them and then clicking in add button, it does not reproduce the same effect, showing only the form from the last addded one.

Comment: Because at that point you've defined the local `$scope.edit`'s so they're not affected by changes in the parent anymore (you can accomplish the same in my last fiddle: using the primitives `$scope.msg="Hello"`). I recommend having an `edit` variable for each trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to NicolasMoise's answer, you may use global scope array to record the state of your individual entries instead of using local $scope.edit's.

The html could be like this:

```
        <li ng-repeat='trigger in triggers'>
            <p ng-hide='$parent.editArray[$index]'>{{trigger.type}} - {{trigger.operator}}</p>
            <form name='editTrigger' ng-show='$parent.editArray[$index]' ng-submit='submit'>
                <select ng-model='trigger.operator' ng-options='op.value as op.name for op in operators' />
                <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Submit' ng-click='$parent.editArray[$index]=!$parent.editArray[$index]' />
            </form>
        </li>
```

And the global edit button would call a function in the controller like this:

```
$scope.toggleEdit = function() {
    $scope.edit = !$scope.edit;
    for (var i=0; i<$scope.editArray.length; i++)
        $scope.editArray[i]=$scope.edit;
}
```

Here's the fiddle that fixes your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/773Pf/2/

I think this is this should have fixed your problem if I understand it correctly.